# notepad++ how to replace with line removal

Tags: notepad++

For example I want to remove every 'test' line..

so ctrl+a to sellect all, ctrl+h for replace and in - to find: I put 'test' but how to REMOVE whole line in - replace width?[replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMb0B.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to well understand your needs, but I assume you want to delete all lines that contains the word "test".

Here is a way to do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*\btest\b.*\R`
- Replace with: `Leave empty`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : begining of line
.*      : 0 or more any character but newline
\b      : word boundary
test    : literally 'test'
\b      : word boundary
.*      : 0 or more any character but newline
\R      : any kind of linebreak
```

DO NOT check `. matches newline`